# Word similar to bookend/tailgate

Tags: single-word-requests

Its a word or phrase that means to stick something onto the end of some other thing, for convenience or even secretly maybe?

An example is I'm going to run errands downtown and when finished will "tailgate" it with dinner in my favourite restaurant there.

Another example, I'm going to the library to work on my business pitch and will "tailgate" it with writing another chapter of my novel

Comment: For me neither 'bookend' nor 'tailgate' means to follow one action with another. 'Bookend' means to surround something with two other things similar to each other but different from the one being surrounded (for example "I bookended a visit to my mother with visits to my two sisters") while "tailgate" specifically means to follow another vehicle so closely as to be dangerous. "Tailgate" may be used in the way you mean in some places but I've never heard it.

Answer (score 1):

To **cap off** will work here. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cap+off)

> Verb  .   cap off - finish or complete, as with some decisive action

As in:

> I'm going to the library to work on my business pitch and will **cap
>   off** the day  with writing another chapter of my novel.

and

He capped off the meeting with a radical proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to run errands downtown and when finished will **follow** it with dinner in my favourite restaurant there.

or

I'm going to run errands downtown and when finished will **follow** it **up** with dinner in my favourite restaurant there.